# Error/Crash when opening AppCompatDialogFragment after Unity Rewarded Video Ad

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, onsaveinstancestate, admob-rewardedvideoad

I would like to open a new DialogFragment after the RewardedVideo Ad has ended.

```
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed()
    {
        //Reward
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {                        new Pop_Like_Google_Play().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");                       
        });
    }
```

However, I just get this error (this only happens with Unity Ads, not with Google or Vungle Ads):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

and this says me that it definetly has something to do with Unity

```
com.google.ads.mediation.unity.UnityMediationAdapter$1.onUnityAdsFinish(UnityMediationAdapter.java:126)
        at com.google.ads.mediation.unity.UnitySingleton$UnitySingletonListener.onUnityAdsFinish(UnitySingleton.java:287)
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this error what I can see the issue is that you are attempting to perform a Fragment Transaction by using `new Pop_Like_Google_Play().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");` which will throw `IllegalStateException`. It might not necessarily be an issue. Since you are using a library you might need to find a way to tweak the way the transaction is being executed in order to prevent this exception from occurring. There is a good [medium post](https://medium.com/@elye.project/handling-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-d4ee8b630066) in which you can read up more about why is this occurring. However, if this is not the case the issue can be identified better with a complete stack trace.